# What these curly braces mean in python Django? *{}*

Tags: python, django

I was working on some code refactoring and i encountered these bad guys. What is their porpouse?
Looks like a formatter but im not pretty sure.

```
                if data:
                    result = ''

                    for recipe_data in data:
                        url = recipe_data['url']
                        name = recipe_data['name']
                        rating = recipe_data['rating']
                        rating_count = recipe_data['ratingcount']
                        prep = recipe_data['prep']
                        cook = recipe_data['cook']
                        ready_in = recipe_data['ready in']
                        calories = recipe_data['calories']

                        result += """
```

*{}*
*{} calories*

Thanks.

Comment: Python string formatting? https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

The following are the use cases of curly braces in Python:

1.**Defining a dictionary**

```
my_dict = { 'key': 'value' }
```

2. **Defining a set**

```
my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

3. **Formatting a string**

```
message = "My name is {} and I am {} years old".format(name, age)
```

Answer (score 0):

they can be used for defining dictionarys to string formatting